# Replace more than one character! how?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, replace

I am trying to replace more than just the one character that I did without any problem. I'm a newbie so I want to make it really simple if it is possible!

```
string input = txtmywords.Text.ToString();
string replacements = input.Replace("a","x");
```

Here i can replace the A with the X. But I want to replace let's say a b c d e f g with x in scentences.

Comment: Wait... do you want to replace each of the different letters with `x`, or the whole string `abcdefg` with `x`?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7265315/1129593) question.

Comment: shaamaan: I want each letter to be replaced no matter where in the scentence they may be written

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this

```
foreach(Char c in "abcdefg")
    input = input.Replace(c, 'x');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could;

```
//System.Text.RegularExpressions

string result = Regex.Replace("zzabcdefghijk", "[abcdefg]", "x");
```

for `"zzxxxxxxxhijk"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace every letter in a given string with another letter (for ease of use) without manually writing a lot of `Replace` every time, you could write something like this:

```
    String ReplaceChars(this string input, string chars, string replacement)
    {
        foreach (var c in chars)
            input = input.Replace(c.ToString(), replacement);
        return input;
    }
```

Then you could write `"abcdefgh".ReplaceChars("acd","x")` and this should get you the string `xbxxefgh`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex for doing it.

```
 public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string input = "This is   text with   far  too   much   " + 
                     "whitespace.";
      string pattern = "\\s+";
      string replacement = " ";
      Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
      string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

      Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
      Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);                             
   }
}
```

Pulling code out from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx