# How To: Use LINQ to search data for a string containing many possible types of "Single Quote"

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The Problem:
My customers want to be able to search for first and last names in my site, using any version of ', `, or those goofy microsoft 'start' and 'end' quotes.

I would like to be able to write a single statement that looks for all possible permutations of that evil symbol, like such:

```
var customers = _sms.CurrentSession.Query<customer>()
                                   .Where(c => c.FirstName.Contains(firstName)
                                            && c.LastName.Contains(lastName)
                                            && !c.IsEmployee)
                                    .ToList();
```

and if the user was searching for "O'Brien", I would show them results for "O'Brien", and "O`Brien", and any other version of that stupid thing.

What's the best way to do that? Is there a way to do it (without a massive recursion where I do things like

```
if (firstName.Contains("'")
{
    var customers = _sms.CurrentSession.Query<customer>()
                                       .Where(c => c.FirstName.Contains(firstName)
                                                && c.LastName.Contains(lastName)
                                                && !c.IsEmployee)
                                    .ToList();

    firstName = firstName.Replace("'", "`");
    customers.AddRange(_sms.CurrentSession.Query<customer>()
                                       .Where(c => c.FirstName.Contains(firstName)
                                                && c.LastName.Contains(lastName)
                                                && !c.IsEmployee)
                                    .ToList());
}
```

etc...

**Update**

```
    private static readonly string[] Quotes = { "@", "'", "‘", "’", "`" };
    private IEnumerable<customer> CustomersByFirstName(string firstName, bool showInactive = true)
    {
        firstName = firstName.Replace(Quotes[1], Quotes[0]);
        var customers = _sms.CurrentSession.Query<customer>()
                            .Where(c => (c.FirstName.Replace(Quotes[1], Quotes[0]).Contains(firstName) ||
                                        c.FirstName.Replace(Quotes[2], Quotes[0]).Contains(firstName) ||
                                        c.FirstName.Replace(Quotes[3], Quotes[0]).Contains(firstName) ||
                                        c.FirstName.Replace(Quotes[4], Quotes[0]).Contains(firstName))
                                        && !c.IsEmployee)
                            .ToList();

        if (!showInactive)
        {
            customers = customers.Where(c => !c.Disabled).ToList();
        }

        return customers;
    }
```

This is almost it... Almost

**Final Update**
This turns out to be exactly the solution, tho not as elegant and small as I might like:

```
    private IEnumerable<customer> CustomersByFirstName(string firstName, bool showInactive = true)
    {
        firstName = firstName.Replace(Quotes[1], Quotes[0]);
        firstName = firstName.Replace(Quotes[2], Quotes[0]);
        firstName = firstName.Replace(Quotes[3], Quotes[0]);
        firstName = firstName.Replace(Quotes[4], Quotes[0]);

        var customers = _sms.CurrentSession.Query<customer>()
                            .Where(c => (c.FirstName.Replace(Quotes[1], Quotes[0]).Contains(firstName) ||
                                        c.FirstName.Replace(Quotes[2], Quotes[0]).Contains(firstName) ||
                                        c.FirstName.Replace(Quotes[3], Quotes[0]).Contains(firstName) ||
                                        c.FirstName.Replace(Quotes[4], Quotes[0]).Contains(firstName))
                                        && !c.IsEmployee)
                            .ToList();

        if (!showInactive)
        {
            customers = customers.Where(c => !c.Disabled).ToList();
        }

        return customers;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like :

```
char[] all_quotes= new char[] { '\'', '‘', '’' /* any other quote you like */ };
```

Then replace them in your names with a special char (lets say `*`), or cut them out all together, and then search for those matches then.

have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7265786/1698987) for an example of how  to do it, or brew your own:

```
var customers = _sms.CurrentSession.Query<customer>()
                   .Where(c => c.FirstName.Replace(all_quotes, "*")
                                          .Contains(firstName.Replace(all_quotes, "*"))
                                        && // same for others)
                                .ToList();
```

**Regarding Final Update:**
I wouldn't have the one to replace as part as the quotes. I'd do something like :

```
string inplace = "@";
private static readonly string[] Quotes = {"'", "‘", "’", "`" };

foreach (var q in Quotes)
    firstName = firstName.Replace(q, inplace);
```

you can wrap the foreach in `{ }` if you'd like. It's shorter, and if you end up adding a quote to the array, you don't need another line of "replace"

Comment: How expensive is something like that when querying a few hundred thousand names, both first and last names?

Comment: the easiest way would be to test it :) if it's a real problem (which it isn't unless you've tested it), you can start thinking on how to improve perfromance :)

Comment: @PKD after reading the accepted answer, performance should be similar, since we're doing something similar. if you're really worried about it, you might be able to get away with changing all your weird quotes to normal quotes in the DB, but it depends on if you want to ignore quotes or not on searches, and on your requirements

Comment: You've actually handled the issue in the requested manner (in the course of the query). But the issue I'm running into is that you can't use a string `"*"` in a replace with a char array.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I posted an answer without fully understanding the question. Here's the corrected answer.

I would define your criteria for a match in a separate function. Here's how I implemented it:

```
    // Add quote characters as needed.
    List<char> quotes = new List<char> { '\'', '‘', '’' };

    public string CleanName(string name)
    {
        StringBuilder cleanName = new StringBuilder(name);
        foreach (char quote in quotes)
        {
            cleanName = cleanName.Replace(quote, '\'');
        }
        return cleanName.ToString();
    }

    public bool IsMatch(string n0, string n1)
    {
        return String.Compare(CleanName(n0), CleanName(n1)) == 0;
    }
```

Then, search for matching names using the IsMatch function, as demonstrated in this unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestQuoteSearch()
    {
        string searchName = "O'Brien";

        var matchingNames = names.Where(name => IsMatch(name, searchName));
        Assert.AreEqual(4, matchingNames.Count());
        Assert.IsTrue(matchingNames.Contains("O'Brien"));
        Assert.IsTrue(matchingNames.Contains("O‘Brien"));
        Assert.IsTrue(matchingNames.Contains("O’Brien"));
        Assert.IsFalse(matchingNames.Contains("Jones"));
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Create Store Procedure and import to Entity Modal then call like method.