# regex.replace c# diacritics

Tags: c#, diacritics, transliteration

I'm trying to replace strings with diacritics, but no luck.
I need to replace, for example "Ю" and "ю" to "yu", "Б" and "б" to "b" and so on with my own table.
I have a such code, which is not working:

```
case "LastRUEN":
                if (csentry["LAST"].IsPresent)
                {
                    string FIELD_RU = csentry["LAST"].Value;
                    string FIELD_EN;
                    FIELD_EN = Regex.Replace(FIELD_RU, "[Аа]", "a");
                    FIELD_EN = Regex.Replace(FIELD_RU, "[Бб]", "b");
                    FIELD_EN = Regex.Replace(FIELD_RU, "[Вв]", "v");
                    FIELD_EN = Regex.Replace(FIELD_RU, "[Гг]", "h");
                    FIELD_EN = Regex.Replace(FIELD_RU, "[Ґґ]", "g");
                    FIELD_EN = Regex.Replace(FIELD_RU, "[Дд]", "d");
                    FIELD_EN = Regex.Replace(FIELD_RU, "[Ее]", "e");
                    mventry["lastNameEN"].Value = FIELD_EN;
}
break;
```

Can anybody hepl with troubleshooting?
Maybe it would be better to use a method for my case?
Thanks!

Comment: That's not diacritics ("accents"), you're apparently trying to transliterate Cyrillic to Latin script.

Comment: Why do you need regex? Can't you just use `string.Replace()`?

Comment: You keep replacing on `FIELD_RU`, which isn't changed. That means that `FIELD_EN` will only ever contain the last replacement. In any case, since you're transliterating, you probably want to go char by char and build the transliterated string based on some dictionary rather than doing string replacements anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work better, because the result of the `Replace` calls will be the input of the next operation.

```
case "LastRUEN":
            if (csentry["LAST"].IsPresent)
            {
                string FIELD_RU = csentry["LAST"].Value;
                string FIELD_EN;
                FIELD_EN = Regex.Replace(FIELD_RU, "[Аа]", "a");
                FIELD_EN = Regex.Replace(FIELD_EN , "[Бб]", "b");
                FIELD_EN = Regex.Replace(FIELD_EN , "[Вв]", "v");
                FIELD_EN = Regex.Replace(FIELD_EN , "[Гг]", "h");
                FIELD_EN = Regex.Replace(FIELD_EN , "[Ґґ]", "g");
                FIELD_EN = Regex.Replace(FIELD_EN , "[Дд]", "d");
                FIELD_EN = Regex.Replace(FIELD_EN , "[Ее]", "e");
                mventry["lastNameEN"].Value = FIELD_EN;
}
break;
```

And of course you should move the operations into a separate method.

EDIT: [Replace Multiple Characters in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265315/replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string) is interessing to combine the multiple calls.

Comment: And if the answer has helped you, please do not forget to mark it as answer.