# C++ function converted to C# function

Tags: c#, c++, string, replace

I have this C++ function that I want to convert into C#.

```
// replace all occurences of a string with another string
void replace_all(string& s, const string& from, const string& to) {
    if(!from.empty()) {
        for(size_t pos = 0; (pos = s.find(from, pos) + 1); pos += to.size()) {
            s.replace(--pos, from.size(), to);
        }
    }
}
```

As specified in the comment, it replaces all occurences of a string with another string, in a given string.

As I have used some C++ functions to replace and find the string, I'm in need of help to convert that function into something that does the same thing in C#.

I am aware of the Regex and I have read a few topics, but could not make much sense of it.

Comment: how about `String.Replace`? This method can be used to replace string occurrence in the given string.

Comment: Does this help you along: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265315/replace-multiple-characters-in-a-c-sharp-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a function working on a small string, you could do something like this:

```
    const string s = "Write code in .Net.";
    Console.WriteLine(s);

    // We must assign the result to a variable.
    // ... Every instance is replaced.
    string v = s.Replace("Net", "Basket");
    Console.WriteLine(v);
```

If you want to work on the same string like in C++, use `StringBuilder`:

```
    const string s = "This is an example.";

    // Create new StringBuilder from string.
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(s);
    Console.WriteLine(b);

    // Replace the first word.
    // ... The result doesn't need assignment.
    b.Replace("This", "Here");
    Console.WriteLine(b);
```