# Replace multiple characters in a string with different characters

Tags: c#, string, list, replace

I am converting a list to string and I am wondering if there is a more simplified way to replace multiple characters w/ different characters. I'm coding in C# and this is what my list looks like:

```
[0]: [Key1, Value1]
[1]: [Key2, Value2]
[2]: [Key3, Value3]
...
```

So basically, I wanted to replace ", " w/ "=" and both "[]" with "" to achieve this format:

```
Key1=Value1
Key2=Value2
Key3=Value3
...
```

I already did get this format using the following code below and I am kinda worried I am overusing the Replace command.

```
string out = string.Join("\n", listOfLines).Replace(", ", "=").Replace("[", "").Replace("]","");
```

I have found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265315/replace-multiple-characters-in-a-c-sharp-string) but it does specify that the characters are all replaced by "\n" only.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the `[Key1, Value1]` a string right from the source, or is it the result of converting an object to String representation?

Comment: @nhahtdh It was actually a dictionary converted to list then to string. That was the only way I could think of that might come up with a string output.

Comment: What would the data look like if a key or a value contained a `,` or a `]`? i.e. if I line were `[7]: [Foo, Bar], Waz]`. What is the the key and the value here?

Comment: @Enigmativity there is a specific format for all the data. Everything was written as [Foo, bar] which represents a simple (key, value) pair

Comment: @ros_beginner - When you say "simple" can you please describe what makes a value key and what makes a valid value?

Comment: @Enigmativity The data is basically use for a startup file in ROS which includes topics and there values. Values are mostly declared in boolean and string

Comment: @ros_beginner - Which is why I'm asking. If a `string` can be the value then can that string contain a `,` or a `]`? If so, that affects how you deal with this problem.

Comment: @Enigmativity I understand that.But if I recall it right, I believe they don't allow special characters except '_' they used this as replacement for spaces

Comment: @ros_beginner - OK, but you've accepted an answer that does have special characters in the solution. It's an unclear question with an unclear answer, in my opinion.

Comment: @Enigmativity keys and values supposedly shouldn't have any special characters.That's what I mean. The '=' sign serves as the delimiter for the values. It is the one saved in the config file.

Comment: @ros_beginner - The `(new DateTime(2020, 1, 1)).ToString()` in the chosen answer has special characters. That doesn't seem to match what you're saying.

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry about that, I don't really mind that DateTime part since I am not using one. The idea of looping through dictionary is what made me accept the answer. This is the idea I also implemented on my current project.

Comment: @ros_beginner - That's fine, but keep in mind that this site's main purpose is to provide a repository of questions and answers **for future readers**. It's not primarily about providing an answer to the person who asked the question. You should always being thinking about how to improve the quality of the questions and answers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned in comment that the data originally came from dictionary, you could loop through the dictionary and format the data as you like.

Sample code with `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("key1", 1);
dict.Add("key2", "string");
dict.Add("key3", true);
dict.Add("key4", new DateTime(2020, 1, 1));

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kv in dict) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}={1}", kv.Key, kv.Value.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. This is very simple and yet what my code requires. Thanks for spending some time helping me out. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid one `Replace` with help of `Regex`.

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"[\[,\]]");
string outval = pattern.Replace(string.Join("\n", listOfLines), "")
                       .Replace(", ", "=");
```

Comment: Hi, this is actually helpful but I prefer not using Replace command a couple of times. Just like what I said, I think I am overusing this method XD. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @ros_beginner  You are always welcome. Its about having different ideas and ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension method similar to that:

```
    public static IEnumerable<char> ReplaceMultiple(this IEnumerable<char> input, Dictionary<char, char> replaces) 
    {
        foreach(var character in input)
            yield return replaces.ContainsKey(character) ? replaces[character] : character;
    }
```

But personally I think, that if there are less than 6-7 character to replace, using multiple Replaces are much more readable.