# c# replace inside textbox string

Tags: c#, string, replace

Hy I have an application that gets his data pushed now from a other system. To communicate this with an api the `,` needs to be removed from the string.

eg:

```
var AMOUNT_INPUT txt_bedrag.txt = 12,30
var AMOUNT_INPUT txt_bedrag.txt = 1230 /*this is the expected result*/
```

I have tried:

I tried to remove the `,` char but that did not work.

How can i fix this so the users dont need to manualy remove the `,` character.

Comment: Why did removing the comma did not work?

Comment: Are you getting this value as a number or string? What code did you write for removing comma?

Comment: That's not even close to valid c# code. Please show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want all the commas out you can use String.Replace() on it:

```
var cleanString = textbox.Text.Replace(",","")
```

Comment: can i also remove a  period and , in the same method ?

Comment: You cannot unfortunately, though you can chain String.Replace() to get the desired result. You can also use regular expression. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7265336/2272438